# Cannot find node module fs when bundling module via scalajs-bundler

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I'm trying to connect a scala.js app to a node module. I have not done this before.

On `fastOptJS::webpack` I am getting a build failure with:

```
target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/fs doesn't exist
target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/fs.webpack.js doesn't exist
target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/fs.web.js doesn't exist
target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/fs.js doesn't exist
target/scala-2.12/scalajs-bundler/main/node_modules/fs.json doesn't exist
```

**build.sbt**

```
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSBundlerPlugin)

name := "Toon Brew"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.9.1"

skip in packageJSDependencies := false

jsDependencies += "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4" / "2.1.4/jquery.js"

npmDependencies in Compile += "fantasy-names" -> "1.1.2"
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.17")

addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalajs-bundler" % "0.6.0")
```

**facade**

```
package toonbrew

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSImport

@JSImport("fantasy-names", JSImport.Namespace)
@js.native
object FantasyNames extends js.Object {
  def names(cat: String, subCat: String, names: Int, gender: Int): js.Array[String] = js.native
}
```

The [entire repo](https://github.com/Synesso/toonbrew/commit/2f48263337e35c6b8d5ac2b4f1cad410216d6699)

How can I get around this error?

Comment: Do you know which dependency does transitively depend on the `fs` module? You can try some options like so: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore `fs` by extending the scalajs-bundler default webpack config.

**no-fs.webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = require('./scalajs.webpack.config');

module.exports.node = {fs: 'empty'};
```

**build.sbt**

```
webpackConfigFile := Some(baseDirectory.value / "no-fs.webpack.config.js")
```

With credit to @julien-richard-foy